# how to solve such a scope issue in javascript for d3.js?

Tags: javascript, scope, d3.js

I'm using d3.js and I found this works:

```
function zoom_in () {
    d3.select(this)
        .select("text")
        .style("font-size","55px");
}
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes, function(d) { return d.name;})
    .enter().append("g")
    .on("mouseover", zoom_in);
```

But this won't work:

```
function zoom_in () {
    d3.select(this)
        .select("text")
        .style("font-size","55px");
}
var already_done = 0;
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes, function(d) { return d.name;})
    .enter().append("g")
    .on("mouseover", function() {zoom_in();already_done=1;})
```

However, I want to do something after I invoke `zoom_in` function.
I don't want to write another function `zoom_in_already_done`.

I think the problem is caused by the `this` variable in `zoom_in`. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Since `already_done` is a global variable, could you just move `already_done = 1;` into the `zoom_in()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way like this:

```
function zoom_in (ts) {
    d3.select(ts)
        .select("text")
        .transition()
        .style("fill",function(d) { return color(d.group);})
        .attr("dx",20)
        .style("font-size","55px");
}
```

Then

```
.on("mouseover", function() {if (dragging==0){zoom_in(this)}})
```